# Port forwarding and NAT using pf on freebsd

Tags: networking, router, nat, freebsd, pf

I have a network router that connects three networks with the outside world. One of the internal networks is public facing the other two are not and connected via NAT. I am part of a larger network and the router has the ip `1.2.3.1` in that larger network, but this ip cannot connect to the outside and only traffic from `external_net` is allowed.

I now want to do port forwarding on the router ip to ssh on a machine in the nat. I am using pf on a freebsd.

My `pf.conf` is:

```
#define network macros                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
uplink_iface = "igb4"
external_iface = "igb3"
l_iface = "igb5"
i_iface = "igb2"
d_iface = "igb1"
external_host = "1.2.3.1/32"

external_net = "1.2.4.0/25"
l_net = $l_iface:network
i_net = $i_iface:network
d_net = $d_iface:network

set skip on lo0

# tell the sender that they are running into pf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
set block-policy return
# do not keep states unnecessarily long                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
set optimization aggressive

#Nat config                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
nat on $uplink_iface from $l_net to any -> $external_host
nat on $uplink_iface from $i_net to any -> $external_host
nat on $uplink_iface from $d_net to any -> $external_host


rdr pass log (all) on { $uplink_iface, $i_iface, $e_iface } proto tcp from any to $external_host port 6987 -> 192.168.2.2 port 22

#do not allow anything but the below rules                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
block all

# allow incoming traffic only to our external IP range/server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
pass from any to $external_net keep state

# allow any outgoing traffic from server and employee machines (tbd)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
pass from { $d_net, $i_net, $l_net, $external_net } to any keep state
```

What I know:

- somehow this does not work from the outside as it times out
- from the inside (i.e., any of the defined nets) a ssh on the port works * the tcpdump of the pflog shows that in both cases the port forwarding is triggered.
- a tpcdump on the corresponding interfaces confirmed that when the
  request is from one of the internal interfaces it is forwarded, when
  it is external it is not.
- when removing `block all` everything works. However, I do not want to drop this rule

**Why can't I connect via ssh from the outside but from the inside?**

Comment: too noisy and vague description TBH, but first q-n is if you tcpdumped pflog why didnt't you tcpdump the SSH traffic itself to verify it goes as you imagine

Comment: @poige How can I make the description more precise. This is 1:1 my pf.conf (besides changed IPs obviously). What do you mean by tcpdump the ssh traffic? I.e., each interface with an ssh filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sufficient to simply redirect the traffic but you also have to allow it. I guess because the `block all` rule comes after the `rdr pass`, block takes precedent.

```
pass proto tcp from any to 192.168.2.2 port 22 keep state
```